# Bootstrap Theme not changing in Chrome, Slightly works in internet explorer (Brand New User)

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, google-chrome

I am trying to follow a tutorial, it got to a point where we were asked to go onto http://bootswatch.com/ and download a theme, I replaced the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css files with the files on the site and it hasn't updated, here is what it looks like in chrome
[Chrome Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMGc9.png)

here is what it looks like in internet explorer

[internet explorer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwQz1.png)

and here is a picture of my version of bootstrap, I believe it is the latest version

[Version Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohxyb.png)

I am a little lost here so any information would be great, sorry if I haven't included something, a bit new.

Comment: If you have downloaded the theme I dont think you have to update any css files. The themes will contain all the necessary files. Can you not replace the files and then see if everything works?

Also in any case if you would like to change the link make sure you have added the rel="stylesheet" to your css link tag.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply :) I think I may have explained it wrong, I went into the css files on the sites, highlighted it all, copied it and pasted it over my css files, it seems to work on the tutorial videos, just not on mine, not sure if its something I havent got installed :( x